# CSS Sprite Animation

Tags: html, css, animation, sprite

Hi I've been trying to do a simple animation with css and a sprite, and it doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something? I've made a JS Fiddle sample.

Can some one explain me why this doesnt work?

http://jsfiddle.net/CmF6A/

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
       <div id="bike">

       </div>
    </div>
</body>

div#wrapper {
    width: 64px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #c0b898;
    margin: auto;
}
@-webkit-keyframes running {
    0% {
        background-position: 0px;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: -320px;
    }
}
#bike{
    width: 64px;
    height: 80px;
    background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/WVPnShz.png');
    -webkit-animation: running 1s steps(6, end) infinite;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with your animation name if you renamed it to something else it works.

```
#bike{
    width: 64px;
    height: 80px;
    background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/WVPnShz.png');
    -webkit-animation: anim 1s steps(6, end) infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim {
    0% {
        background-position: 0px;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: -320px;
    }
}
```

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/CmF6A/2/

Comment: I also think 'running' is an animation `keyword` so that's why it won't work.

Comment: Tnx Paulie_D it helped a lot ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JSfiddle :)

I have simply updated your own fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/CmF6A/5/

```
#bike{
width: 64px;
height: 80px;
background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/WVPnShz.png');
animation:myfirst 5s;
      -webkit-animation:myfirst 5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

@keyframes myfirst
{
    from {background-position:0px;}
    to {background-position:-320px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */
{ 
    from {background-position:0px;}
    to {background-position:-320px;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial to create Sprite sheet animation

**https://medium.com/@Mrugraj/sprite-sheet-animation-using-html-css-9091bebd4eeb**

```
.animatedDiv {
    width: 820px;
    height: 312px;
    background-image: url("https://cf.dropboxstatic.com/static/images/index/animation-strips/hero-intro-bg-vflR5rUow.jpg");
    -webkit-animation: play 2s steps(48) infinite;
    -moz-animation: play 2s steps(48) infinite;
    -ms-animation: play 2s steps(48) infinite;
    -o-animation: play 2s steps(48) infinite;
    animation: play 2s steps(48) infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes play {
    from {
        background-position: 0px;
    }
    to {
        background-position: -39360px;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes play {
    from {
        background-position: 0px;
    }
    to {
        background-position: -39360px;
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes play {
    from {
        background-position: 0px;
    }
    to {
        background-position: -39360px;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes play {
    from {
        background-position: 0px;
    }
    to {
        background-position: -39360px;
    }
}
@keyframes play {
    from {
        background-position: 0px;
    }
    to {
        background-position: -39360px;
    }
}
```